# How to make pytesseract work in collab python?

Tags: python, computer-vision, python-imaging-library, tesseract, python-tesseract

I tried to follow different steps by researching but neither of the steps are helping in executing the pytesseract code.

Downloaded tesseract exe from https://github.com/UB-Mannheim/tesseract/wiki.

Installed this exe in `C:\Program Files\Tesseract-OCR`

installed `pytesseract` using `pip`

imported `pytesseract`

```
pytesseract.pytesseract.tesseract_cmd = r'C:\\Program Files\\Tesseract-OCR\\tesseract.exe'
    
a = pytesseract.image_to_string(PIL.Image.open('/content/drive/MyDrive/hindi_image.jpg'),lang='hin')
```

but this steps throw error

```
FileNotFoundError                         Traceback (most recent call last)
    /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/pytesseract/pytesseract.py in run_tesseract(input_filename, output_filename_base, extension, lang, config, nice, timeout)
        253     try:
    --> 254         proc = subprocess.Popen(cmd_args, **subprocess_args())
        255     except OSError as e:
    
    6 frames
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'tesseract': 'tesseract'
    
During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
    
TesseractNotFoundError                    Traceback (most recent call last)
    /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/pytesseract/pytesseract.py in run_tesseract(input_filename, output_filename_base, extension, lang, config, nice, timeout)
        256         if e.errno != ENOENT:
        257             raise e
    --> 258         raise TesseractNotFoundError()
        259 
        260     with timeout_manager(proc, timeout) as error_string:
    
TesseractNotFoundError: tesseract is not installed or it's not in your PATH. See README file for more information.
```

[In my local system the path is same as above](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iWDlX.png)

How can I resolve this please help.
Thankyou!

Comment: `Google Collab` runs on `server` with `Linux` so you can't use path to tesseract on your `local` `Windows`. You have to install tesseract on server (probably using `!apt install tesseract-ocr`) and use path to this version.

Comment: I runs `pytesseract` on local Linux and after installing `tesseract` it runs even without setting path in code because `tesseract` is automatically installed in folder which is on environment variable `PATH` and `pytesseract` can find it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Google Collab` runs on `server` with `Linux` so you can't use path to your `local` `Windows`.

You have to install `tesseract` for Linux on server using

```
!apt install tesseract-ocr
```

and use path to this version.

---

But maybe you will not have use this path in code because `apt` should install `tesseract` in folder which is on environment variable `PATH` and code should find `tesseract` without path.

I run `pytesseract` on local Linux and I don't have to set path in code.

---

If you will need to use language different than English then you can see all available languages

```
!apt search tesseract
```

and install like (ie. Hindi)

```
!apt install tesseract-ocr-hin
```

It may need also to add option `lang='hin'` in `pytesseract` to use this language.
To use both languages you can try `lang='hin+eng'`

---

**EDIT:**

I tested on `Google Colab` - after installing `!apt install tesseract-ocr` I can use `pytesseract` without setting path.

---

**EDIT:**

`pytesseract` writes image to file and runs `tesseract` with path to this file and it writes result in text file, and later `pytesseract` reads result from text file.

But you can send directly path. And later read result from text file.

```
import pytesseract

pytesseract.pytesseract.run_tesseract('path/to/image.png', 'output', 'txt', lang='hin')

with open('output.txt') as fh:
    result = fh.read()

print(result)
```

or even

```
import pytesseract

def file_to_text(filename, *args, **kwargs):
    pytesseract.pytesseract.run_tesseract(filename, 'output', 'txt', *args, **kwargs)
    with open('output.txt') as fh:
        return fh.read()

# ---

text = file_to_text('path/to/image.png', lang='hin')

print(text.strip())
```